# TSQL Divide set in groups

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with 3 fields: wk, cor, id

"wk" is the week, "cor" groups items from same location, "id" is the id of each item to retrieve from warehouse.

Given a certain number of items to retrieve, I must take almost the same quantity of items from each group ("cor" represents groups) for balancing the warehouse performance, respecting the week precedence (before going to the following week, the previous must be ehausted).

If you follow the link the image may be clear:
[Data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/123lK.png)
rows are taken in this order:
yellow, orange, green, gray (this last one starts with "cor 2" because "cor 1" was the last used in week 28)

The RES column (done by hand in the sample) represents the right order I should take items; currently this is obtained with a cursor, which is very very slow and I'd like to do something better, if possible; I've tried with windowed functions, cte, recursive cte but was not able to get anything right.

With this script you can have the same table

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (wk int, cor int, id int)
INSERT INTO @t
     (
         wk
        ,cor
        ,id
     )
VALUES
(28,1,4044534),
(28,1,6778322),
(28,1,7921336),
(28,1,4326390),
(28,2,2669622),
(28,2,6580257),
(28,2,1179795),
(28,3,3980111),
(28,3,2549129),
(28,3,6763533),
(29,1,6023538),
(29,1,8219574),
(29,1,3836858),
(29,2,3355314),
(29,2,148847),
(29,2,8083320),
(29,3,1359966),
(29,3,8746308)
```

The expected result:
*All fields are given* while the **RES field must be calculated and represents the order in which items will be taken out** (explained below the table).

```
+----+-----+---------+-----+
| wk | cor |   id    | RES |
+----+-----+---------+-----+
| 28 |   1 | 4044534 |   1 |
| 28 |   1 | 6778322 |   4 |
| 28 |   1 | 7921336 |   7 |
| 28 |   1 | 4326390 |  10 |
| 28 |   2 | 2669622 |   2 |
| 28 |   2 | 6580257 |   5 |
| 28 |   2 | 1179795 |   8 |
| 28 |   3 | 3980111 |   3 |
| 28 |   3 | 2549129 |   6 |
| 28 |   3 | 6763533 |   9 |
| 29 |   1 | 6023538 |  11 |
| 29 |   1 | 8219574 |  14 |
| 29 |   1 | 3836858 |  17 |
| 29 |   2 | 3355314 |  12 |
| 29 |   2 |  148847 |  15 |
| 29 |   2 | 8083320 |  18 |
| 29 |   3 | 1359966 |  13 |
| 29 |   3 | 8746308 |  16 |
+----+-----+---------+-----+
```

The algo is like that:

1. The older week must be first exausted (in the sample, wk 28 must be finished before taking itmes from wk 29)
2. Items must be equally reparted in "cor"s, so if 10 items are required they must come out like that: 3 from cor1,3 from cor2, 3 from cor3. The last one may come from whichever cor because 10 is not divisible by 3, obv
3. If 11 items are required; week 28 only contains 10 items so the last one will be taken from week 29, with the same principle: equally distribute the exit among cors, even if  weeks change. If the last article from week 28 was taken from cor 1, the next one in week 29 will be taken from cor 2

Comment: Can you explain the logic of assigning value for the RES column?

Comment: Can you post the expected result

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Ok, sorry, give me few minutes and and I'll format it...

Comment: Include it on the question, in the comments cant be read it. check here for a format table tool: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96125/how-to-format-sql-tables-in-a-stack-overflow-post

Comment: Can you post the cursor you have that is producing the correct results. As it sits right now the desired output makes no sense to me at all. There is some rule about sorting that is not clear.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza the cursor it not very comprehensable and not done by me,...
The algo is like that:
1) The olderweek must be first exausted (in the sample, wk 28 must be finished before taking itmes from wk 29)
2) Items must be equally reparted in the "cor", so if 10 items are required they must come out like that: 3 from cor1,3 from cor2, 3 from cor3. The last one may come from whichever cor because 10 is not divisble by 3, obv

Comment: Was @SeanLange asking. The problem is very hard to understand the question. Simplify the data show the specific example in the question not the comments. Show us very clear your logic so even a duck can understand. We love to solve problems, but trying to understand cryptic questions is annoying.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: We need both source data and expected output, and if possible what is your current output and current query so we can see what have you tried and what is wrong. Right now looks like only desire output is provided. Without source data we cant do anything.

Comment: You have to tell us how RES is calculated.  So far you have told us nothing about this.  We cannot read your mind or see what specs you are working from, you have to tell us.

Comment: I'll try tomorrow morning, or even this night, and let you know. Many thanks to all of you and forgive me if I was not that clear initially

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this answer your problem ?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp2

CREATE TABLE #temp (idx INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1), wk int, cor int, id int)
INSERT INTO #temp
VALUES
(28,1,4044534),
(28,1,6778322),
(28,1,7921336),
(28,1,4326390),
(28,2,2669622),
(28,2,6580257),
(28,2,1179795),
(28,3,3980111),
(28,3,2549129),
(28,3,6763533),
(29,1,6023538),
(29,1,8219574),
(29,1,3836858),
(29,2,3355314),
(29,2,148847),
(29,2,8083320),
(29,3,1359966),
(29,3,8746308)

SELECT wk, cor, id
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY wk, RES, idx) as RES
FROM (
    SELECT  idx
        ,   wk
        ,   cor
        ,   id
        ,   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY wk, cor ORDER BY cor) AS RES
    FROM    #temp
    ) AS t
ORDER BY idx
```

Comment: I think so, I'll test a bit; believe me or not but you all save my life :)
I must study because it seems it works but can't uderstand how: I've passed all this afternoon trying to solve it and in minutes you did it ? I'm frustrated ;)

Comment: Note that you need an identity in your table to make this to work.

Yes I know the pain, I used to have similar issues and had to play around with this ROW_NUMBER() function.

Comment: @MaximeDaniou, instead of using the column with identity property it's possible to use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0)`. But this case requires careful performance testing.

Comment: I can confirm it works and gave same result as the old one with cursors.
Comparing plans: with cursor about 94% of time, 6% this new one!

Comment: Very nice.
Can you confirm that the use of a table variable was only to provide us with a sample of your data?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the correct information in your test data to support the desired output. 
If however, you were to have an identity column that represents the insertion order, you could use something like the following...

```
WITH cte_RankOrder AS (
        SELECT 
            t.rn, t.wk, t.cor, t.id,
            RankOrder = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY t.wk, t.cor ORDER BY t.rn, t.wk)
        FROM
            @t t
        )
SELECT 
    ro.rn, ro.wk, ro.cor, ro.id,
    RES = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY wk, ro.RankOrder, ro.cor)
FROM
    cte_RankOrder ro
ORDER BY ro.rn;
```

results...

```
rn          wk          cor         id          RES
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
1           28          1           4044534     1
2           28          1           6778322     4
3           28          1           7921336     7
4           28          1           4326390     10
5           28          2           2669622     2
6           28          2           6580257     5
7           28          2           1179795     8
8           28          3           3980111     3
9           28          3           2549129     6
10          28          3           6763533     9
11          29          1           6023538     11
12          29          1           8219574     14
13          29          1           3836858     17
14          29          2           3355314     12
15          29          2           148847      15
16          29          2           8083320     18
17          29          3           1359966     13
18          29          3           8746308     16
```

HTH, Jason